# React TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access a local array file, filter it, and store the filtred array as a state, finally pass the state to child component.

```
// array file

const originalData =
[ 
  { "ComName":"A", "SDGs":"1", "No":1 },
  { "ComName":"B", "SDGs":"2", "No":2 },
  ...
]
```

I use `getComany()` and `filterCompany()` to get the filtred data, and store it in `filtredCompany` as a state. But it turns out `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in null`.

```
// Services.js

export function getCompany() {
  const companyList = originalData;
  return companyList;
}

export function filterCompany(comType) {
  // filter detail

  let companyList = getCompany();
  let filtredMatchCompany = getCompany().filter(type => type.SDGs === comType && type.No == comType);
  let matchCom = _.map(filtredMatchCompany, 'ComName');
  let filtredCompany = companyList.filter((type)=> matchCom.includes(type.ComName))
```

```
// Filter.js

export default function Filter() {
  const [filtredCompany,setFiltredCompany] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFiltredCompany(getCompany());
  }, []);
  
  function handleD3(e) {
    let typeCompany = e.target.value;
    typeCompany !== "all"
      ? setFiltredCompany(filterCompany(typeCompany))
      : setFiltredCompany(getCompany()); 
  }

  const outputFilter = filtredCompany;

  return (
    <>
      {buttons &&
        buttons.map((type, series) => (
          <>
              <button key={series} value={type.no} onClick={handleD3}>
                  {type.name}
              </button>
          </>
        ))}
          <>
             <ObjectD3 outputFilter = {filtredCompany}/>
          </>
   </>
}
```

The error might come from initial state `null`. I try to fix that, and change the initial state to
`const [filtredCompany,setFiltredCompany] = useState([])` . TypeError doesn't occur, but setState, which is `setFiltredCompany` , doesn't work anymore.

```
  const [filtredCompany,setFiltredCompany] = useState(null);
  console.log(filtredCompany)
  // *click button*
  // the filtred data I want


  const [filtredCompany,setFiltredCompany] = useState([]);
  console.log(filtredCompany)
  // *click button*
  // []
```

Does anyone know how to handle this situation or better idea to pass data? Thank you so much in advanced!

[Source code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-meitner-j9usb?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you Bergi. I edit my question, please check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let go through a part of your [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-meitner-j9usb?file=/src/App.js) here.

First of all, for a React Component, the lifecycle methods are executed in the following order: **constructor -> render -> componentDidMount**.

Within the **Filter** component, you are setting initial state like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setFiltredCompany(getCompany());
}, []);
```

Now, one thing to remember is all the **setState()** functions and the **useEffect** hook, are **asynchronous**, that is, they complete their execution at some time in the future. So, when React renders your app, by the time **ObjectD3** component is rendered, the **useEffect** hook has not executed, so
the ObjectD3 receives **null** as a prop and the statement in ObjectD3

```
this.dataset = this.props.outputFilter;
```

assigns null to the dataset, thereby giving you the error.

A better way to do it, is to implement another lifecycle method in ObjectD3, named componentDidUpdate, where you can compare the changes in props, since the update and take necessary actions.

Check the updated version of code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-currying-d1i7e?file=/src/ObjectD3.js).

Comment: Hi Charchit, thank you for answering. Parameter `comType ` here would be `typeCompany`, which access `<button>` attribute `value`, and return string type back. In other words, I logged this function and it works.

Comment: Please try implementing a minimal version of your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new?file=/src/App.js). Then I will be able to help you easily.

Comment: Hi Charchit, I have pack it up [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-meitner-j9usb?file=/src/App.js). Thanks for help.

Comment: You're amazing Chartchit, that is what I want to know. One more question: What should I modify code to update canvus on its own position when clicking, instead of generating new canvus below?

Comment: We should clear the content of myRef, which refers to the div of the ObjectD3 component, each time generateCanvas function is called. This can be done I think using JS DOM manipulation methods. Check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-clear-the-content-of-a-div-using-javascript/#:~:text=How%20to%20clear%20the%20content%20of%20a%20div%20using%20JavaScript%3F,-Difficulty%20Level%20%3A%20Easy&text=JavaScript%20provides%20the%20functionality%20of,property%20and%20removeChild()%20method.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231889/discussion-between-vik-huang-and-charchit-kapoor).